# Ubuntu 20.04 suspend issue

Tags: 20.04

I am working with Ubuntu for a while now but the last 3 days suspend seems to be broken.
It suspends successfully but after waking up it takes some time in black screen and the it just restarts.
I have recently updated eveything.
Can somebody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem on a new machine. Sometimes suspend works as expected. Sometimes it messes up the monitor configuration, either changing from side-by-side to mirror, or moving all the windows on the second monitor over to the first. Sometimes it won't return from suspend at all; just now even holding the power button down wasn't enough. I had to unplug the machine to recover.

Comment: The issue had been resolved for me